# Composition of composition not working

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, composition

I am currently using RIA services with an object containing a child containing itself a child and it's not working     :-( !

I have an update method for the BaseObject and the FirstChild are correctly present in the client but it behaves as if I have no SecondChild object (the type is not event created on the client)...

Here are the classes:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(BaseObjectMetaData))]
public partial class BaseObject 
{ 
    internal class BaseObjectMetaData
    {
        [Include, Composition]
        EntityCollection<FirstChild> FirstChilds { get; set; }
    }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(FirstChildMetaData))]
public partial class FirstChild: 
{
    internal class FirstChildMetaData
    {
        [Include, Composition]
        EntityCollection<SencondChild> SecondChilds { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to also attribute your Collection property with the **AssociationAttribute** as well as include a **ForeignKey** on your entity class and reference it in the attributes ctor arguments, remember to include the **DataMemberAttribute** as well (entity framework already does this by default on generated members)

[heres](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2009/11/20/wcf-ria-services-and-dto-with-association.aspx) an article outlining it further